# unable to load font awesome icons in html

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am working on a front end project where I have to load `font awesome` icons in my page . I included in my `<head>` tag  the link :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Then I tried loading a picture in my html like     `<span class="focus-input100 fa">&#xf095;</span>`
which I had seen from another post here . However the pic does not load . This is the first time I am using `font awesome` and I would appreciate your help.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<span class="focus-input100 fa">&#xf095;</span>
```

EDIT : I check the page console and find the error :

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/HTML_FILES/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/%E2%80%A6' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Comment: Hmm, [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/joLaz60h/). Any errors in your console?

Comment: @j08691 Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/HTML_FILES/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/%E2%80%A6' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: see my solution below @VasilisSkentos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>
<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
<i class="fas fa-car"></i>
<i class="fas fa-file"></i>
<i class="fas fa-bars"></i><br/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<i class="material-icons">computer</i>
<i class="material-icons">traffic</i><br/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
```